# Does AMD llano APU support triple display?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm a little bit excited about AMD's new APU.

I googled about its capability of triple display, but could not find an answer. I looked at a motherboard, http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128511

It looks like it supports triple display, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think so, and besides Llano uses lowend GPUs just like IGPs in AMD motherboards so I doubt you could run 3 displays, at least not smoothly